# Vaadin Flow: How to get current URI

Tags: uri, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin12

I need to get the current servers name an all the other information stored in the `URI`.
In Vaadin 8 it was accessible thru the `Page` by calling something like this:

```
URI uri = Page.getCurrent().getLocation();
```

In Flow the `Page` does not contain such information:
[image]

An neither does the `Router` afaik.

---

How do I get the `URI`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Update Feb 2021

Since Vaadin 19 there is a new `Page` method called `fetchCurrentURL` which will actively poll the current url form the frontend.

see: [commit](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/pull/10024/commits/95d706457adea7e0e2de1aadd48b720cc73f5fa4)

---

## Old and potentially problematic workaround

The URI can be retrieved using this:

```
VaadinServletRequest req = (VaadinServletRequest) VaadinService.getCurrentRequest();
StringBuffer uriString = req.getRequestURL();
URI uri = new URI(uriString.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way of doing this, but a feature request is open for this case: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/1897.

Comment: This is no longer true as the feature has been implemented.